# I want to make an array in Fortran 95 with mixed variables

Tags: arrays, variables, fortran

I am new into Fortran and I want to make an array that has both real and characters I tried making a type that lets me have real variables at the first column of the array and characters at the other but it didn't work.The variables I have come from a .txt file.
Is there any option to read the variables before getting them in the array or a custom type is the only choice? Thanks in advance!!

The example program is

```
PROGRAM HOMEWORK 
  IMPLICIT NONE 
  integer::i 
  type custom
    real :: data 
    character :: name 
  end type 
  type (custom), dimension (4) :: AA 

  OPEN(5,FILE="askhsh_fortran.dat") 
  do i=1,4 
    read(5,*) AA(i) % data , AA(i) % name 
  end do 
  WRITE(*,*)AA 
  close (5) 
END PROGRAM HOMEWORK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a variable to have both reals and characters, then you will need to create a custom type, e.g., some code fragments:

```
type MyType
   real :: data
   character (len=20) :: name
end MyType 

type (MyType), dimension (10) :: table

do i=1, 10
   read (5, *) table (i) % data, table (i) % name
end do
```

Comment: I fixed error 57 but when I  have a character in the .txt the program displays error 52-invalid character in field.. Thanks in advance again!!

Comment: This is a good example.  If you want to learn more the key phrase is "derived data type"

Comment: this is the part of my code after following instructions


`PROGRAM HOMEWORK
IMPLICIT NONE

integer::i
type custom 
   real :: data
   character :: name
  end type
type (custom), dimension (4) :: AA
OPEN(5,FILE="askhsh_fortran.dat")
do i=1,4  
read(5,*) AA(i) % data , AA(i)  % name
end do 
WRITE(*,*)AA
close (5)
END PROGRAM HOMEWORK`

Although the .txt has 4 reals in it when i try to run the program it displays error 57.. @M.S.B, @Mark S

Comment: @NikosPapanikolaou I've edited your question to include this example (comments are not a good place for extended code blocks). Could you also edit the question to include an example for the file askhsh_fortran.dat, it's not clear at the moment if the 4 reals are all on one line, one per line, two per line etc. Note error 57 is usually given along with the message "attempt to read past end-of-file" which should explain what the issue is here.

Comment: @d_1999 It is not always the best course of action to pursue new errors which emerge after implementing the solution from the correct answer to the existing question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300966/dealing-with-solutions-that-end-with-a-new-error http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: @VladimirF thanks, I realised after I'd submitted edits to this that it may end up confusing things if the question keeps evolving but unfortunately there was no way to retract. Many thanks for the links, I'm still getting my bearings with regards stackexchange best practice etc

Comment: @d_1999 I am myself not sure what is the best thing to do here. One could just change the question completely before getting an actual help, but as there is now an accepted and upvoted answer it should not be invalidated. I can remove the code from the question myself easily but I am not sure I should do it.